# how to do Highlight, Add Notes, and Capture/Share the text on the screen of PDFPage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Can anybody please let me know any free thirparty sdk or source code using which I can Highlight, Add Notes, and Capture/Share the text on the screen like iBooks

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be with OCR of the PPDFPage, I recommend Tesseract 
http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ 
https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo

Then you want to look for code to "add notes" to a UITextView, the highlighting can be done via a UITextView and the capture/share can be done via CoreGraphics and whatever built in sharing method you want to use.

Comment: thanks for Reply @albert but github link not working please can you give me any other links?

Comment: The code isn't working or the site isn't loading? It works for me.

Comment: Here is a link to the zip file download of that code: https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo/archive/master.zip

Comment: nice now link is working i will tel you after check and text demo of tesseract. :)

Comment: its demo not working dude app Crashing while picking image from ImagePicker :)

Comment: <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0 or Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0

Comment: Wow, lots of errors, I think it's having issues resizing whatever images you used... did you try using just the camera? Are you on an iPhone5? I got EXC_Bad Access when I ran the code, I googled and found some revisions, not sure if they are free-use but they could be good for basing your fixes off of: haven't tested them, but you can check out his lines of code here: http://vtecvcs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/VnOCR/IOS/

Comment: thank you so much albert for your effort  i will check and when i solve this i will let you know above it :) thanks again